# How laravel cache works?

Tags: php, laravel, redis

how does the cache in laravel work?
I use the function `Cache::remember` to save for 5 seconds the response to the request, and when the time expires it will be updated again, but this does not happen for some reason

cache driver - redis

without caching the function gives fresh results, but with caching - the old results

code example

```
public function last_win()
{
    return Cache::remember("last-wins", config("cache-config.cache_time.last-wins"), function () {
        return GameBet::with("getGame")
            ->where('created_at', '<=', Carbon::now())
            ->where("win", ">", 0)
            ->orderBy("created_at", "desc")
            ->orderBy("id", "desc")
            ->simplePaginate(25)
            ->toArray();
    });
}
```

in config:

```
"cache_time" => [
    "last-wins" => env("CACHE_TIME_LAST_WINS", 5), // 5 sec
],
```

please tell me what i'm doing wrong:)

Comment: Stranger Things... cleared the cache via redis-cli ( FLUSHALL cmd) and it worked, I do not know why, maybe anyone have a similar problem with redis?

Comment: My guess is that you created the cached value in redis with some earlier code that had a longer TTL (or no TTL) and so when running your most recent code it always found that first cached value. Only when you cleared redis did it add the values with the correct TTL and work as expected.